# Cannot import tensorflow in Spyder but it imports in python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

I installed  Anaconda on my machine and created a separate environment for tensorflow. Installed tensorflow and keras ok but both packages cannot be imported. The error is:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-88d96843a926>", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Dependencies that were installed during the install like scipy and yaml *can* be imported.

When I run python3 from the command line I can import keras and tensorflow correctly. This fails when I try to import tensorflow in Spyder.

I rebooted, uninstalled and installed again. I am sure that I am in the correct environment. Does somebody know what I do wrong?

Comment: Is Spyder installed in the same environment as Tensorflow and Keras? If it's not, it would explain what you're seeing. Conda environments are pretty much isolated from one another.

Comment: That was  it. I installed Spyder in my new environment and it worked. Thank you very much!